# Use of next() and store next line in variable

Tags: python

I am trying to grab the next line where a condition is met.

```
for line in file_two:
    if line.startswith('Query='):
        line = line.rstrip()
        header = line
        header_2 = next(line)
        print (header)
        print (header_2)
```

It is giving following error:

```
header2 = next(line)

TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `next` on the iterator, in this case the next line will be gotten from `file_two`:

```
header_2 = next(file_two)
```

note that as [@KlausD. has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36549369/use-of-next-and-store-next-line-in-variable/36549442?noredirect=1#comment60699573_36549442) this will skip the next line in the regular iteration, to also get that line in the for loop you can `.seek()` back to the original position:

```
pos = file_two.tell() #tell the current position
header_2 = next(line)
file_two.seek(pos) #go back to the beginning of the line
```

or alternately use a boolean flag to to indicate when to handle the next line:

```
after_header = False
for line in file_two:
    if line.startswith('Query='):
        line = line.rstrip()
        header = line
        #header_2 = next(line) #don't get the next line yet
        after_header = True #signal for next cycle
        print (header)
    elif after_header:
        header_2 = line
        print(line)
        after_header = False
```

Comment: This will as a side-effect forward the iterator on the file, or in other words: skip every second line.

Comment: I guess that wasn't obviously the intent... Well thank you for pointing it out @KlausD.

Comment: Actually I just need to take the line which is just next to header line so for me header_2 = next(file_two) worked

Comment: @MaseumUmairSeemab, I figured that was the intent.